# How to do code colourful if it bocomes grey when I use suitable code in language injections?

Tags: python, pycharm

I installed Database Navigator to do my SQLite code colourful. But when I try to switch my code in SQLite via language navigator. it becomes grey. How to do it colourful?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOIn2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BshVA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open your SQLite file in IntelliJ IDEA.

Go to File -> Settings to open the setting.

In the settings dialog go to Editor -> Color Scheme -> Database -> SQL.

In the right panel, you will see the list of syntax elements for SQL code. Look for the element named SQLite Keyword or similar.

Clic on the color box next to SQLite Keyword and choose a color that you prefer. You can also customize the font style, background color, and other properties for different elements.

Repeat the that step for other syntax elements you want to customize, such as SQLite Function, SQLite Table Name, etc...

When you have made the changes, click Apply or OK to save the settings.